# Publishing to npm, file defined in `main` is not published

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to publish a package to `npm` and for some reason the `.js` I've defined in the `package.json` isn't included with the package. My project is written in `typescript` and I transpile via the following npm script...

```
"prepublishOnly": "tsc -p ./ --outDir dist/"
```

Which correctly outputs the file I expect to `dist/app.js` locally. I then do an `npm publish` and the `readme.md` and some other files are published, but not the `app.js` I expect to be. The `package.json` has the main set as `dist/app.js` so what am I missing here?

This is my first npm package publish, so it's probably something stupid, happy to try any ideas.

Comment: Does your `.gitignore` exclude `dist/`?

Comment: It does, but my .npmignore should override it shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is most likely because you have a `.gitignore` file, which npm will respect as a fallback if no [`.npmignore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file is found. I am guessing you are running into the above, perhaps ignoring `/dist` in source control?

> If there's no .npmignore file, but there is a .gitignore file, then
>   npm will ignore the stuff matched by the .gitignore file

[`main`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) will not actually dictate what content is packed...

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your
>   program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs
>   it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports
>   object will be returned.

Additionally, packaged files can explicitly included via [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files)

```
"files": ["dist/app.js", "/and/others/"]
```

And lastly, if you take a peek at [npm/issues/3571](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3571), you can workaround this by simply adding an empty `.npmignore` file.

> If you want to include something that is excluded by your `.gitignore`
>   file, you can create an empty `.npmignore` file to override it.

---

**pro tip** - you can run [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) locally, which will execute all the lifecycle hooks of a publish and provide you the `.tgz` package as if it were fetched from npm. You can unzip this to inspect the contents. I've found this super useful on many occasions to emulate publishing without actually doing so.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

Comment: Great response, lots of stuff to try thanks. If I empty my `.npmignore` and pack I get everything except from the `dist` folder which I presume is because my transpile only happens pre-publish.

Comment: I solved this by explicitly adding a `files: []` entry, still slightly confused as to why it didn't work with an empty `.npmignore` but the files from `dist` are now packaged, so I'm happy! Double +1 for the `npm pack` command, this is a significant time saver!